# correct way to close an MS Access form assigned to variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a progress indicator form.

I use the following code to turn it on and off. Turning it off with .visible=false and Set object=nothing works but is the form still open in memory?

```
dim oProgInd as Form_frmProgressIndicator
set oProgInd = new Form_frmProgressIndicator
   With oProgInd
        .Status="Running Append"
        .visible=true
        .maxRecord=iMxRec
   End with
   Do
      ' some repetitive code
      oProgInd.Tick
   Loop
   oProgInd.visible=false
set oProgInd=nothing
```

I know Excel VBA uses Unload to close a form. Should I be using some kind of Unload in MS Access VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set oProgInd=nothing` will release the reference to the form class object.  Since there are presumably no other references to it, it should get closed.

You can confirm in the Immediate window by inspecting the `Forms` collection:

```vb
? forms.Count
' if Count > 0, use this "for each" to see the form names ...
for each frm in forms : ? frm.name : next
```

Comment: As a heads up, when you set a form variable = nothing, the forms.count will not usually get updated until a do events is executed.